# How do i get the names or arguments inside the method definition?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to get a list of the argument names in a method?

For example, suppose I have the following method definition:

```
def speak(name, age, address)
  # some code
end
```

How can I get an array of `name`, `age`, and `address`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is there a way to return a method parameter names in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2452077/#2452322), [Reflection on method parameters in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3456827/#3460072), [Any ruby library to inspect what are the arguments that a certain methods take?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6420695/#6425175) and [Ruby: How to inspect the parameters of an instance method without creating a new instance?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6717912/#6717939).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the values directly.

```
def speak(name, age, address)
  puts "Hello #{name}!"
end
```

To access the names you could use `local_variables` but I don't really recommend it.

```
def speak(name, age, address)
  p local_variables # => [:name, :age, :address]
end
```

But most likely you'll want to use a hash:

```
def speak(hash)
   # use the keys/values of hash
end
```

Now you can use

```
speak({:name => "foo", :age => 42, :address => "123"})
# or
speak(:name => "foo", :age => 42, :address => "123")
```

Comment: I am talking about the argument's variable name. I know this might sound kind of stupid because I am already supposed to know the naem of the variables of the arguments.

Comment: So why can't you just use Hash as an argument to your method? Then you will be able to collect passed name-value pairs. Why not?

Comment: I know that using hash is the easiest way to go but I am just wondering whether it is possible to get the argument's variable names without using hash as the method argument.

Comment: @denniss: See edited answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `local_variables` for it, but there is a better way:

```
def speak(name, age, address)
  p self.method(__method__).parameters #=> [[:req, :name], 
                                            [:req, :age], 
                                            [:req, :address]]
end
```

When you are using `local_variables` you should use it at the beginning of the method:

```
def speak(name, age, address)
  foo = 1
  p local_variables #=> [:name, :age, :address, :foo]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
def speak (name, age, address)
 puts local_variables
end
```